# Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'Oauth'

Tags: python, oauth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up temperature logger using the DS18b20 temperature sensor.  I have been following the steps in Chap 10 of the book "Raspberry Pi projects for Dummies".  After creating a temperature logger spreadsheet in Googledocs, the next step in the chap is to store data logged by my Raspberry Pi onto the temperature log spreadsheet saved on GoogleDocs.  I have created the spreadsheet, downloaded the prerequisite programs templogger_gdocs.py, ds18b20.py and gdocs.py.  I ran the emplogger_gdocs.py program and entered the client id, secret and spreadsheet key and saved the changes.  I've carefully checked for typos.  I'm then supposed to type "python templogger_gdocs.py and it should take me to www.google.com/device and give me a code, but instead I get the following:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "templogger_gdocs.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "templogger_gdocs.py", line 48, in main
    LogRowInGDocSpreadsheet(client_id, client_secret, spreadsheet_key, headings, temperature, unit_of_measure);
  File "/root/rpipfd/gdocs.py", line 14, in LogRowInGDocSpreadsheet
    oauth = gaugette.oauth.OAuth(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OAuth'
```

My question is how do I get the OAuth module I need to get the code?

From my research on the last 2 days, it seems like I need a token as well.  I have this, but I don't know where to enter it.

Below (starting with !/usr/bin/env..) is what I get when I run the templogger_gdocs.py program.

```
!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Rapsberry Pi Projects For Dummies: temperature logger to google docs spreadsheet
For the Raspberry Pi
"""
import subprocess
import time
from ds18b20 import GetTemperature
from gdocs import LogRowInGDocSpreadsheet

    ds18b20_dir     = "XXXXX"
    client_id       = "XXXXX"
    client_secret   = "XXXXX"
    spreadsheet_key = "XXXXX"
    fahrenheit      = False
    headings = ["Temperature", "Date", "Unit"] #column headings can't have 
    spaces

    def main():
            # This is the main routine of the program

            # set how long to wait between logs
            poll_interval = 5

            if fahrenheit:
                    unit_of_measure = 'F'
            else:
                    unit_of_measure = 'C'
```

I have a feeling it needs updating. The book was published in 2015, and it could be out of date. It seems like there is an OAuth2 and a json token now.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking oauth2 is needed. I would recommend using the gdata library instead. I can't even find documentation on the gdocs lib. Alternatively there is also the sheets API.

Comment: Thanks Greg.  I think it's a good idea that I try another data logging program.  There are alot of other options.